# How to add an anchor <a> tag / html to a Swal call

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I am trying to add an anchor tag to my swal tag (I am using *Sweetalert* with cdn). Is there any way to do this specifically with jQuery (**not Angular/React**)?

I have tried using a variable with the value of the link as below:

```js
swal({
text: "foo",
content: "link" + (backtick)<a href="link">Link</a>(backtick)
});
```

But why this did not work?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version are you using? Because SweetAlert2 has a `html` property. [documentation](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#custom-html)

Comment: I don't know, the cdn I'm using is : <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script> but I don't know if that helps

Comment: That helped. That is [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/). Now there is a [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) which is more powerful. I suggest you to simply change cdn for [this one](https://unpkg.com/browse/sweetalert2@11.3.10/dist/). You will need the JS and the CSS. You will have to adatp you code a little...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Louys pointed out in the comment above, use **SweetAlert2** (the latest)

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Then you can utilise the `html` field, like so:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: '<strong>HTML <u>example</u></strong>',
  icon: 'info',
  html:
    'You can use <b>bold text</b>, ' +
    '<a href="//sweetalert2.github.io">links</a> ' +
    'and other HTML tags'
})
```

Using a 'template literal' - backticks (`) - you can insert variables and add a link like so:

```js
var my_link = 'http://google.com';
Swal.fire({
  title: '<strong>HTML <u>example</u></strong>',
  icon: 'info',
  html: `<a href="${my_link}">Click here!</a>`
})
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much, It Helped